# Obtaining client computer name on local network in javascript asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, networking, client-side, internal

I have an asp.net (FW 3.5) web app that runs on an internal network. One specific page needs to "report" in to the web server that it is active and not locked up.  I need to be able to run a script (or something) at the client to report the pc's computer name in that report.  I cannot find a method that does this.  I found several things that would report the WAN IP or host name, but this appears to all be for external facing sites.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your app has to be config'd for Windows Authentication.  I got this off the net some years ago, but it still works for us:

```
Dim host As System.Net.IPHostEntry
host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Context.Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST"))
dim machineName as string = host.HostName
```

Wrap that up in some kind of repeating/timed ajax call on the client and you've got a webpage that phones home every x often.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The app has to use forms auth.  Most of the app is available externally, only this page is not.